# luatex 1.12.0 and babel

Tags: luatex, babel

On my system (Linux 5.6.14-arch1-1) the following compiles fine with pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}
Hallo
\end{document}
```

However, compiling it with LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) gives this error:

```
(/home/m/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def

! LaTeX Error: Command \bbl@foreign@x already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Removing and reinstalling TeX Live 2020 gave the same result. I suspect it is a local problem on my computer. Or does anyone have a similar experience to report?

Comment: Very related: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/69. Can you post the full `.log` file of the example? Did you try rebuilding the format?

Comment: That seems to have been it -- rebuilding the format did the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuilding the format". I'm having the same error with pdfLaTeX (I write mostly in Spanish). This started happening today and I upgraded my TeXLive distro (Debian Testing) yesterday.

Comment: As explained in the link: fmtutil -user --all.